# Not able to import name from root of the project

Tags: python-3.x, api, falconframework

I am having a server.py file which is written in Falcon. Which looks like this.

```
try:
    import falcon, logging
    from os.path import dirname, realpath, join
    from wsgiref import simple_server
    from .config.config import server_config
    from .middlewares.SQLAlchemySessionManager import SQLAlchemySessionManager
    from .middlewares.GlobalInternalServerErrorManager import InternalServerErrorManager
    from .lib.dbConnector import Session
    from .routes import router
except ImportError as err:
    falcon = None
    raise err


serv_conf = server_config()
salescoachbot = falcon.API(middleware= [
    SQLAlchemySessionManager(Session),
    InternalServerErrorManager()
])
```

But when I am trying to import "salescoachbot" to other folder and files 
like:

```
from ..server import salescoachbot
```

This gives me an error saying that the

```
 from ..server import salescoachbot
 ImportError: cannot import name 'salescoachbot'
```

The server.py is in the root of the project and has an **init**.py as well as the file which is trying to import the name.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm sure you just have recursive imports. Try to refactor.